# soap request client to webservice using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wcf, web-services, soap-client

My question is similar to

[How do I send/Receive SOAP messages usiung .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524017/how-do-i-send-receive-soap-messages-usiung-net)

I wanted to invoke a webservice, however not like the way shown in the link above.What I did was, created a service reference with the wsdl url(in a windows application with a button click event)

```
http://ipaddress:port/My/MyService?wsdl
```

have created a client object

```
Dim objProxy As MyClient = New MyClient()
```

I have populated the objrequest and objreqheader using the below methods, (assigning string values and not xml)

```
objreqheader.id = "abcd"
```

Finally the below line invokes the service

```
objresponsehead = objProxy.myoperation(objreqheader, objrequest, objresp)
```

From reference vb, this is the myoperation public function

```
Public Function myoperation(ByVal RequestHeader As AFA.RequestHeaderType, ByVal GetTransactionDetailsReq As AFA.GetTransactionDetailsReqType, <System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute()> ByRef GetTransactionDetailsResp As AFA.GetTransactionDetailsRespType) As AFA.ResponseHeaderType
            Dim inValue As AFA.getTransactionDetailsRequest = New AFA.getTransactionDetailsRequest()
            inValue.RequestHeader = RequestHeader
            inValue.GetTransactionDetailsReq = GetTransactionDetailsReq
            Dim retVal As AFA.getTransactionDetailsResponse = CType(Me,AFA.myservice).getTransactionDetails(inValue)
            GetTransactionDetailsResp = retVal.GetTransactionDetailsResp
            Return retVal.ResponseHeader
        End Function
```

The problem is my objresp is coming as empty. There is no exception generated, objresponsehead is populated as "abcd". The service is not invoked. I am not sure how to get the trace file from the app config file, to debug the issue. I remember, when i used this for the first time, got an error "no endpoint listening that could accept the message", however there is no error now.

I added the below in the app config file to get the trace to see what is going on. But did not see any trace file(trace.log) generated.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" name="TextWriter"              initializeData="trace.log" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

I checked the property of objProxy, it is having basic http binding as the property. 
Anyone invoked the service like this? From soapui, the response is fine, after i populate the request fields.

How can i enable the trace to see what is the request going and where is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731859.aspx):

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
                 <add name="messages"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
          </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
</system.diagnostics>

<system.serviceModel>
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging 
         logEntireMessage="true" 
         logMalformedMessages="false"
         logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" 
         logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
         maxMessagesToLog="3000"
         maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
  </diagnostics>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Initially I got an error "There was an error in serializing body of message getTransactionDetailsRequest: 'There was an error generating the XML document.'.  Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.PlainXmlWriter+MaxSizeExceededException". When i change the size, the error dissappeared. However, not able to see any logs generated.

Comment: The problem i had earlier was the response was not conforming to the wsdl. This, I checked using the validate response option, within soapui tool. Is there any way to generate the logs related to this, in .net client?There was no exception in my .net client, except the response object was blank, even though i could see the response xml in the trace log.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a switch you can turn on. Please ask a separate question on that, and you may get an answer.