# response validation for soap client

Tags: vb.net, soap-client

This is related to my question at the below link, however posting on a seperate thread as needed some direction on the error handling part.

[soap request client to webservice using vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653187/soap-request-client-to-webservice-using-vb-net)

How/Where can i get the error "response validation not conforming to wsdl and schema" in my vb.net webservice client. I checked the response using the validate response option, within soapui tool. Is there any way to generate the logs related to this, in .net 
client?There was no exception in my .net client, except the response object was blank, even though i could see the response xml in the trace log.

The below line invokes the webservice. After the excution, tracelog has the request and response xml, however my objresp(response object) is empty. In soapui, i validated the response, it was not conforming to schema.

```
objresponsehead = objProxy.myoperation(objreqheader, objrequest, objresp)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the proxy classes that got generated. Remove the [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]. Add the below switch, which is the diagnostic switch for the xmlserializer. Then step throgh the code that deserializes the response from the webservice.

```
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
<switches>
<add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="1" />
</switches>
</system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```